# How to convert portions of a webpage and create a styled and formatted PDF on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, pdf

I am building a WordPress website for a company and they want users to be able to click a button and have Management Bio Profiles be converted to a PDF on-the-fly.  This PDF bio will be a derivative of the content on the webpage and have a different layout than the webpage.

If the webpage bio is changed then the PDF should reflect this the next time it is downloaded by a user. They do not want to maintain and upload dedicated PDF's and upload them to the media library.

Essentially they want to mimic the functionality found on this page when you click the PDF icon below the contact info.  [http://www.bht.com/ryan-berger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to make .pdf files on the fly within Wordpress sites. It'll likely take a little time for you to build the layout using FPDF's methods (FPDF uses an XY coordinate system to represent the .pdf page and takes some getting used to).

Basically you'd:

1. Copy the FPDF class files into your theme directory, which you can download from their [website](http://www.fpdf.org/)
2. Include the FPDF class in your Management Bio Profiles template like so: `require('/your-theme/path/to/fpdf.php');`
3. Create a new FPDF object and pull in all of the Management Bio Profile content that you'd like included and set the layout of where you want those elements
4. Make a `<a></a>` linking to the newly created .pdf

Comment: Working like a charm!  Thanks for helping us out on this one.